# How can we get the object from the AWS S3 bucket when the key is defined with folder structure?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Here is the sample code.

```
String bucket = "test-b1";
String key = "9781557751188/FullBookCover_JPG/book_98989.pdf";

AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsDetails.getAccess_key(),
                    awsDetails.getSecret_key());
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, clientConfiguration);
S3Object s3Obj = client.getObject(bucket , key );
S3ObjectInputStream s3is = s3Obj.getObjectContent();
```

getObject is not returning the expected object.

Comment: May you please tell us what is this key and how did you get it?

Comment: The key is configured in a database (while updating the object to the s3 the path is stored as a key to retrieve). The file is available in the s3 bucket with the folder structure.

The key from the s3 bucket is : 9781557751188/Image PDF/9781557751188.pdf. It will be same in the DB also.

Comment: Then what is the issue here? Have you verified in S3 if same object there what you are getting?

Comment: @code_mechanic 
With the below code my issue has been solved.     
  GetObjectRequest s3ObjectReq = new GetObjectRequest(awsDetails.getBucketName(), docName);
    S3Object s3Obj = client.getObject(s3ObjectReq);
    S3ObjectInputStream s3is = s3Obj.getObjectContent();

Answer (score 0):

With the below code my issue has been solved.

```
String key = "9781557751188/FullBookCover_JPG/book_98989.pdf";
    GetObjectRequest s3ObjectReq = new GetObjectRequest(awsDetails.getBucketName(), key);
        S3Object s3Obj = client.getObject(s3ObjectReq);
        S3ObjectInputStream s3is = s3Obj.getObjectContent();
```

I am able to get the file inside the folder with this code